# Is there a manual for Finder?

Tags: finder

I know the Mac's tend to work intuitively... ;)

Having said that, I often have wondered where the missing manual for Finder is hidden...

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a manual but try this:

Switch to the Finder and select "Mac Help" in the Help menu.
Then search for Finder in the Mac Help window.

Try also the online help at http://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.11/ . (Use 10.10 for Yosemite and 10.12 for Sierra.)

Comment: Well, i know all that, but i am looking for: shortcuts par example to move around with arrow keys; specific unix based commands i am not aware off..etc etc. i expect to find a pdf manual for these things that are so basic...